# Switching between branches Git on Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I am new to Git and do not understand everything yet. I usually commit after each app update and then create a new branch for the next app version, so that I can correct bugs of the currently published version while working on improving the app for future versions.

So far it was just a precaution and I never really used it that way but I want to get serious about Git capabilities. And I face this problem:

**I have two branches in addition to the master, and if I compare the files from the two branches, I can clearly see the differences.
However, if I "checkout" from one branch to the other, nothing happens and it seems that the current code is just reassigned to a different branch.
But what I want to do is to be able to modify both codes in parallel.**

How does it work?

Thanks.

Comment: You can not do that. At most you can stash the changes and apply it to the other branch.

Comment: @MuratK. is correct. Here's a reference: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Comment: Arf, I thought it was the whole point of git. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to do the changes in one branch. Then you can share the same change to other branch using git. There are multiple ways to share the changes, based on the different scenario.

They are "Cherry pick", "patch", "merge" and "stash"(additionally shelve in android-studio).

Based on the scenario shared above, you can use patch to share the code among branches.

1. Make changes in one branch and commit it.
2. Right click the `commit` in android-studio and select "`create patch`".
3. Checkout to another branch.
4. Select options `VCS` ---> `Apply Patch`.
5. Select the "`patch`" file and apply it.
6. Now you can able to see the changes you made in the "other branch" in "current branch".
7. Then you can `commit` the changes in the regular way.